# WSO2CEP : Visualization of data through Line and Bar charts

Tags: bar-chart, dashboard, linechart, wso2-cep

I am having a hard time to get data displayed on gadgets in `wso2cep dashboard`. Stream containing data is something like:

```
    ts            ssh_logins
2016-05-08 08:59       1
2016-05-08 09:00       2  
2016-05-08 09:01       12
2016-05-08 09:14       20
```

where ts is string which I need to set as x-axis and ssh_logins is a long variable to be selected as y-axis. Now when I select a `line chart`, I couldn't get a plot as it doesnot allow to choose string as x-axis. How to overcome that? I also tried `bar-chart` but bars are not being populated when data come. Below is image to demonstrate. Is there a way to plot these simple values using available gadgets in `wso2cep dashboard`?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the same stream with bar chart and I was able to plot it by making ts as x axis and ssh_logins as y axis.Please see the attached image. Can you tell how did you send data to dashboard ? For the line chart, yes it a limitation, we have fixed it and will available in the future release. Also what is the cep version you are using ?

[image: Bar chart]

Comment: Thank you for the response. I didn't get your question about how I am sending data. However I am using a stream. Are you asking anything specific? The version is 4.1.0. I am logging and displaying data at the same time. Logger works fine and even axis gets populated but bars doesn't get showed up.

Comment: If you have choose ssh_logins data type as long then an issue may come.  This is a known bug and already fixed in the master branch. Can you please change the data type to int in the stream and check.

Comment: I had to delete and recreate the gadget, then it worked. Please update the reason so I could mark your answer correct. Also there is a slight irregularity. x-axis values are set in a random manner not in order events are being sent. i.e. I am getting 8:59 -> 9:14 -> 9:01 -> 9:13 -> 9:00. However logger is printing them in order. What could that be about?

Comment: reason for not getting plotted when used long as data type is a bug which is fixed in the master branch. I sent the events one by one in 08:59  - 9:00 ->  09:01 ->  09:14 using event simulator. I could see events plotted in order. How did you send the events? using a csv file ?

Comment: I have used a log file which has  the timestamps and other info. I worte siddhi query to extract count of log entries within one minute using Stream#window.timeBatch(1 min). Then I sent it to logger and ui